# Unity 3D Build error in XCode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, build, virtual-reality

I am trying to build my first Unity 3D app to Xcode ever. I have tried looking at multiple different sources trying to make sure that I have all my settings correct, but for whatever reason [I keep getting these errors in my Xcode workspace.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da0aE.png)
I have tried following [these instructions from the Unity page to no avail.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-ios-device-testing) I feel like my problem is a common one that people face when first starting out. If someone could enlighten me to what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it. Here is what [my player setting looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH6Q2.png) Please let me know if there is another picture needed to figure out the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good news! Those are not errors, those are warnings! Errors are red circles with exclamation points. GTMSessionFetcher is a "pod" - basically a plugin - so you can pretty much ignore those warnings, since that's not your code. The only warning you might want to look at is the top one, which is just Xcode encouraging you to update your project settings. Double click on that warning to get some suggestions on how to fix it.

Edit: you know I just now realized that Xcode error icons are octagons, not circles, like stop signs.